# Blur a background using a photo

Tags: photoshop

How can I create a photo that would blur the layers behind it in Photoshop? I need this for my website and I'll explain it a bit more below...

So lets say that I've got a background layer in Photoshop of Mario.
I create a new layer and create an image that will blur the background of Mario.
How can I create that "blur-image"?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a photoshop than a photography question. You need to find something like 'Gaussian Blur' option in photoshop and apply that to the layer you want to blur.

Comment: @Vikas Well it's not that I need that background of Mario because the background is supposed to be my website and the "blur-image" is supposed to blur my website, but I suppose this is not yet possible.

Comment: You will need to do this with some kind of javascript, not a blurred photo (what happens if the photo is a different size to the user's browser?).

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077759/image-blur-with-css-javascript-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a JavaScript library to do image blurring on the site. A quick google search found [this option](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/). The link points to a demonstration page showing how you can blur an image with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an image that will blur another image by overlaying it.

You can make a semi-transparent image that will lower the contrast of the underlaying image (i.e. a milky/smoky overlay). That works because you can do the adjustment on each separate pixel. You can't do blurring the same way, because there each pixel will be affected by the surrounding pixels.